# I wanted to connect to internet from my PC through windows mobile phone

Tags: windows, tethering

I have HP Ipaq 6515c with windows mobile 2003se, and connect to internet with GPRS.  I want connect to internet with my PC through my phone, but can't find any anything about internet sharing in my phone or any software. Help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a 21-days-trial version of [WMWifiRouter](http://global.wmwifirouter.com/features/) which can do what you want, but I'm not sure because your Windows Mobile version is a bit old.

> Turn any windows mobile into WIFI
>   router. WMWifiRouter instantly turns
>   your wifi enabled Windows Mobile based
>   smartphone into a wireless internet
>   hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

I used [PdaNet](http://www.junefabrics.com) on my old WinMo phone.  I think you can use it for free but only on non-secured sites.  To get to secured sites you have to buy the full versi.

I now use the paid Android version and I'm very happy with it.